# Strange Interaction Trigger Behavior

Tags: wpf, command, interaction, eventtrigger

I have two Datagrids. You can switch Items between it by Doubleclinking on one or more rows.
The doubleclick event is handled by a command sending the list of selected items to the viewmodel.

So i have Datagrid 1 with Trigger:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick" SourceName="lstProducts">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=Add}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lstProducts, Path=SelectedItems}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And Datagrid 2 Trigger:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick"  SourceName="dgProducts">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=Remove}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgProducts,Path=SelectedItems}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Everytime I double Click on a Datagrid it calls the Add AND Remove Command. But when I set a debug Point inside both delegate Command Methods it only enters one. If I set it in only one, no matter which one, it will enter it.

For example having clicked in the first datagrid it should call the Add Command, so it stops at the breakpoint. But also when I set the breakpoint to remove, but not on both.

I tried to apply the **SourceName** and even the **SourceObject** but it wont help..

Maybe anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: No one knows a solution?

Comment: I don't understand part "Everytime I double Click on a Datagrid it calls the Add AND Remove Command." Until this line I thought that you have some "select many form a set control". But in this case only one handler would be invoked for each double click.

Comment: I added a MouseDoubleClick Trigger for each Datagrid calling a diferent command. So when I click on first DataGrid it should only call the Add Command and on the second it should only call the Remove command. But it calls both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have your scenario working properly:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Added { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Available { get; set; }

    public ICommand Add { get; set; }

    public ICommand Remove { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Added = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        Available = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        Available.Add(new Product { Id = 1 });
        Available.Add(new Product { Id = 2 });
        Available.Add(new Product { Id = 3 });
        Available.Add(new Product { Id = 4 });
        Available.Add(new Product { Id = 5 });
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        Add = new RelayCommand<IEnumerable>(x =>
        {
            foreach (Product item in x.Cast<Product>().ToArray())
            {
                Added.Add(item);
                Available.Remove(item);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("add");
        });

        Remove = new RelayCommand<IEnumerable>(x =>
        {
            foreach (Product item in x.Cast<Product>().ToArray())
            {
                Added.Remove(item);
                Available.Add(item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("remove");
        });
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and xaml:

```
<StackPanel >

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Available}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" x:Name="lstProducts">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick" SourceName="lstProducts">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=Add}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lstProducts, Path=SelectedItems}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </DataGrid>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Added}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" x:Name="lstProductsAdded" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick" SourceName="lstProductsAdded">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=Remove}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lstProductsAdded, Path=SelectedItems}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </DataGrid>

</StackPanel>
```

Is this what you did/wanted to do? In my sample just one command is executed. And you can see it in Output window.

I figured out how to break this code to reproduce your behavior: in both i:EventTrigger tags you have the same SoruceName so you bind to single grid.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. It seems you really want to help me with my problems :) 
Thats nearly the excat reproduction of my code.
The SourceName is not the same, one is lstProducts and one is dgProducts.
When I set a breakpoint in Add it goes into Add even clicking on Remove, and vise versa. But when I set both Breakpoints it only enters one.... Very strange...

Comment: try to run my code and see what happens :) maybe you'll see the difference or it will work as you describe on your environment. This would mean that we have different dlls of mvvmlight. Note that I downloaded this project today (4.0.23.1).